# Is rounding over addition distributive?

Tags: relations

I am trying to answer the question whether:

```
Round(a + b + c) = Round(a) + Round(b) + Round(c)
```

(Forgive me if "distributive" is the wrong term, been some time since my math days)

Context:

I have financial transactions data in which each amount is written in cents. Due to historical error, some of the amounts had 2 numbers after the decimal points (for example 300.02 cents which is $3.00**02**).

At the end of each month, we would sum up all transactions and round the result. I want to fix the historical error so that I only have integers in my data and I was wondering if the results with bad data (after rounding) would still equal the results with fixed data.

Thanks!

Comment: Try $0.0033+0.0033+0.0033$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let a = b = c = 1.2 Then Round$(1.2+1.2+1.2)$ = Round$(3.6)=4$, but $3$Round$(1.2)=3.$ Generally, you should always round after the calculations are done, if possible.

Comment: Right! I don't know why my intuition  tricked me, all I had to do was plug a simple example